# Show a splash screen within the Application class

Tags: android, network-programming, splash-screen, urbanairship.com

In my Android app I'm doing a remote settings call in the Application class since it contains values I need for a library which must be initialised in the Application class onCreate().

There's two big issues with this however. One being that I have to join the network thread with the main thread to make sure that we got the values before the end of the onCreate method. The other issue being that sometimes a call can take a long time to make so I would prefer showing a splash screen before making the call and then removing it when the call is done. This is, from that I've understood, not possible in the Application class and must be done within an Activity.

The library in particular that must be initialised in Application is Urban Airship and if someone have any idea how to show a splash screen in the Application class, launch Urban Airship outside this method or maybe some other solution to this I would be grateful.

Comment: Did you try searching?  Judging from the first page of google results, there are lots of tutorials and code examples of how to do a splash screen.

Comment: Oh yes I did, been doing it for hours and all of the ones I found were splash screens initialised in the Activity and not the Application. Having a class named Application makes it hard to google to start with. Maybe I'm just bad at searching, can you provide a link with a proper solution?

Comment: What's wrong with doing it from an Activity?

Comment: As I stated in my question, I'm using a library that need to be initialised in onCreate in the Application class. Initialising it anywhere else causes it not to function properly. The settings for the library is controller from my server so I need to make a network call before it initialises to fetch the settings. Having a black screen stay in a couple of settings looks bad so I want to hide it under a splash screen. An Activity is initialised after the Application is finished so it's no good.

Comment: Could you start a thread from onCreate in the Application to do the initialization, which would allow the UI thread to continue its business?  Or would the library not allow that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I can't but I'm doing some tests on it right now. Need to get hold of a slower phone or something too be sure that it's stable enough to release.

Comment: The android emulator tends to be pretty dang slow.  And if that isn't slow enough, running it with a debugger attached it's REALLY slow.